# Using the gofmt refactoring tool to rename a global variable

Tags: go, refactoring

I'm experimenting the `gofmt` tool capabilities for refactoring [[image]go](/questions/tagged/go) code based on this [blog post](http://spf13.com/post/go-fmt), I have this trivial example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var v = 12

func main() {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

I'm trying to **rename** the `v` variable to `m`applying this recipe:

```
gofmt -r 'v -> m' -w main.go
```

The code after the refactoring looks (broken) like:

```
package m

import (
    "fmt"
)

var m = m

func m() {
    m
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a problem with what you're trying, the [gofmt manual states](http://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/):

> The rewrite rule specified with the -r flag must be a string of the form:
>
> `pattern -> replacement`
>
> Both pattern and replacement must be valid Go expressions. In the pattern, **single-character lowercase >identifiers serve as wildcards** matching arbitrary sub-expressions; those expressions will be substituted for the same identifiers in the replacement.

(highlighting added)

If you had `var vee = 12` and used `-r vee -> foo` everything would be fine. With `v -> m` however,
`v -> m` matches every Go expression, identifies it as `v` and replaces it by `m`.

Comment: Huh. Why is using single-character lowercase identifiers to match "arbitrary sub-expressions" useful? (Or is that another question...)

Comment: @Matt An example directly from the doc: `(a) -> a` to remove unnecessary parentheses around expressions.

Comment: Ah, I see. So it can be used for more than just refactoring variables but also cleaning up syntax. Thanks.